# SEL as a instance property or as static variable

Tags: iphone

I want to keep track of a callback method in one of my class instance... so that i can call this method later on.
How can i do this ..? i thought of storing the reference of call back method in one of the instance variable(SEL datatype). if i am using SEL as the datatype what attributes should i give for the @property...or can i declare this as a static variable... How can i do this..
I am new to iphone .. Pls anybody help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i am using SEL as the datatype what attributes should i give for the @property...

A `SEL` is not an NSObject, so it must be `assign`.

> or can i declare this as a static variable...

You can declare anything as static variable.